# Manage with json values , java

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to java and I have a little problem with parsed JSON data, down below you can see my code, I parsed JSON data into `ListView` as you can see in my code, now I want to add click listener to each item in the `ListView`, and when the user clicks the item that he wants it should open the url link of the chose item, I tried via intent but I don't know how to update the **uri** field from JSON, thanks in advance.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  // Dismiss the progress dialog
  if (pDialog.isShowing())
      pDialog.dismiss();

  /**
   * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
   * */
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
          MainActivity.this, contactList,
          R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
          "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
          R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String url = "email";
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
      }
  });

  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}


{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "senjo",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c202",
                "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c203",
                "name": "John Wayne",
                "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
```

Comment: What about `contactList.get(position)`? There is a position in the onItemClick event so you can get the position of the clicked item

Comment: I have not tried it, but can you write the code please, cause i am new to this and i would like detailed answer, thank you

Comment: I don't know how your objects look in your `contactList`

Comment: I updated the question, you can see the json file

Comment: I don't need your JSON, I need to know how your objects look in your `contactList`

Comment: So i want to get the email value from my json and update it to the onclick listener , just simple

Comment: I will cooperate more, and what is wrong not knowing something, i am beginner in this, i don't understand good some things, how to explain how my objects look, i am creating a simple app,for you who know these things good its simple, that is what i meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145462/discussion-between-festim-dehar-and-denny).

Answer (score 0):

To Open the URL your should try this

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Yes i know, but url should be taken from json , i have key named url:http...... , it should open automatically the url of the specific list item

Comment: well then please paste the whole code as looking to your code I guess you are troubling with setting intent, the doubt is what is your JSON format and how you are handling it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do that:

```java
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
MainActivity.this, contactList,
R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email", "mobile"}, 
    new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String url = contactList.get(position).get("url");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit: OK, from your edit, it looks like you don't actually have a `url` field in your JSON. If the `url` you mean to open is actually the email address, then you have to use this instead:

```java
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String email = contactList.get(position).get("email");
        if (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + email));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i will try this and let you know

Comment: I tried it and it crashes my app, this app is not responding, how to make contactList variable final

Comment: Hi Leo @AsoLeo can you help me regarding something, can we use chat